# How to pass EventHandler to enable button in parent form from a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have followed this https://rjcodeadvance.com/iu-moderno-temas-multicolor-aleatorio-resaltar-boton-form-activo-winform-c/ to create a Windows Forms user interface for an application I am planning.

I am trying to enable a button in the **parent form** based on the results of a successful login from a **child form**.

I have managed to do it, and it works, with this code. When login is successful, the button in the parent form is enabled.

```
        private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Close();
            ActivateButton(btnSender);
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
            this.panelDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();


            FormLogin frmlgn = new FormLogin();
            frmlgn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler(child_DataAvailable);
            
            frmlgn.Show();

            lblTitle.Text = childForm.Text;
            btnClose.Visible = true;
            btnMaximize.Visible = true;
            btnMinimize.Visible = true;
            btnClose.BringToFront();
            btnMaximize.BringToFront();
            btnMinimize.BringToFront();
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the child form isn't shown inside a panel anymore, which breaks the user interface.

As you can guess, the method performs several modifications to show the form passed as a parameter inside the panel so everything is shown in the same "window".

If I change  `frmlgn.Show();` to  `childForm.Show();`, I break the EventHandler mechanism, and the button is not enabled, although I keep the user interface as I would like to. When I run the code, as shown above, event handling works but the Login form is shown as a separate window, instead of inside the main window.

I can't figure out how to keep the user interface intact while transferring the data to enable the button.

Everything I try shows some kind of error while compiling. The closest I have been is trying to change `frmlgn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler(child_DataAvailable);` to `childForm.DataAvailable += new EventHandler(child_DataAvailable)` but it says *CS1061 'Form' does not contain a definition for 'DataAvailable' and no accessible extension method ... *

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

**Update**!!

Well I have managed to get it working, although I would like to have a "cleaner" approach, if possible.

I have just created an *if* loop that executes the modifications to the particular Login form and then shows it in the panel. If the Form to load is different from Login then it executes the code as "is". Thankfully it works, but I don't feel comfortable with this little trick. I am sure there has to be a clean way of doing this.

```
      private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
        {
            if (childForm.Name == "FormLogin")
            {
                FormLogin frmlgn = new FormLogin();
                if (activeForm != null)
                    activeForm.Close();
                ActivateButton(btnSender);
                activeForm = childForm;
                frmlgn.TopLevel = false;
                frmlgn.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                frmlgn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(frmlgn);
                this.panelDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
                frmlgn.BringToFront();
                frmlgn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler(child_DataAvailable);
                frmlgn.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                if (activeForm != null)
                    activeForm.Close();
                ActivateButton(btnSender);
                activeForm = childForm;
                childForm.TopLevel = false;
                childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
                this.panelDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
                childForm.BringToFront();
                childForm.Show();
            }
            lblTitle.Text = childForm.Text;
            btnClose.Visible = true;
            btnMaximize.Visible = true;
            btnMinimize.Visible = true;
            btnClose.BringToFront();
            btnMaximize.BringToFront();
            btnMinimize.BringToFront();
        }
```

Please note that compiling showed a serious exception (not shown in errors tab) that said that *Top-level control cannot be added to a control*.
I had to change this line `this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);` to `panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(frmlgn);` and I don't really know what consequences it may have.

Thanks again.

Comment: Is the spelling correct DataAvilable?

Comment: It wasn't, thanks for pointing out.